# JScript date compare

Tags: javascript

```
var FSO     = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var BFolder = "C:\\temp";
var XFolder = FSO.GetFolder(BFolder+"\\");
var FList   = new Enumerator(XFolder.Files);
var today   = new Date();

for (; !FList.atEnd(); FList.moveNext()) {

   var d = FList.item().DateLastModified;
   if (d.getMonth() == today.getMonth) { // <----- *

   }
   else {

   }
}
```

How do I make the above comparison (*) work?

Comment: You should probably add your question to the post. It's not totally obvious as a comment in the code

Comment: You should also describe in detail _how_ it's not "working".

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `today.getMonth()` in stead of `today.getMonth`
And perhaps replace

```
var d = FList.item().DateLastModified;
```

by

```
var d = new Date(FList.item().DateLastModified);
```

Comment: The last thing depends on what `FList.item().DateLastModified` represents; I hope not an arbitrary string, as that's not specified and implementation-dependent.

Comment: var d = new Date(FList.item().DateLastModified); This is what I need. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d` is a `Date` object you can compare months this way:

```
if (d.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) { …
```

(you need to *call* `Date.getMonth`).